Extracting a vector from two columns of a data.frame, which with ggplot2 replaces labels in scale_discrete()
I need to replace very long axis labels in a ggplot with more informative names stored in the dataframe from which the plot is drawn.
For some reasons (see Replacing axis labels with scale_x_discrete) ggplot fails to do so.
Here is an example of the original plot x-axis:

The original labels (n=256) are grouped in a way, that three of them belong to the same factor level (basically, they are replicates).
The solution is to create a vector, which specifies the replacing label for each of the original labels.
z <- c("SKF1_sample_001" = "Cat1",
       "SKF1_sample_002" = "Cat1",
       "SKF1_sample_003" = "Cat1",
       "SKF1_sample_004" = "Catn",

        .....) ### for all 256 labels ### note that "Catn" does not follow a logical pattern

and use this vector in scale_x_discrete(labels = z)
I do not want to write a  vector with 256 revalues, so i am trying to extract this from the dataframe (see the link above, how this fails when used directly).
I am collecting the required data (original and replacement labels) in tmp.
From tmp i want to extract a vector which can be used by ggplot2 for scale_x_discrete(), so it must put the extracted values in "" and separates all value pairs with ",", exactly as in vector z.
Any help is appreciated!
Here is an example data set:
tmp <- data.frame(Original = c("Sample001", "Sample002", "Sample003", "Sample004", "Sample005"),
                 Replacement = c("Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat2"))

I tried z <- paste(tmp$Original,"=", tmp$Replacement, collapse = ","), which is not working with ggplot2! The obtained vector does not feature the "".

tibble::deframe(tmp) or with(tmp, setNames(Replacement, Original))

Possible dup: Converting two columns of a data frame to a named vector.

thanks for the answer. ggplot2 then requires scale_x_discrete(names(z)) to correctly draw the new labels.

tmp <- data.frame(Original = c("Sample001", "Sample002", "Sample003", "Sample004", "Sample005"),
  Replacement = c("Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat2"))

labels <- setNames(tmp$Replacement,tmp$Original)

ggplot(tmp, aes(x = Original, y = runif(nrow(tmp)))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)

